# ORA-01418 specified index does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to increase the column length of a particular column in a table using the SQL below:

```
ALTER TABLE ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B MODIFY ALTERNATIVEID VARCHAR2(52);
```

This results in the following error:

```
ORA-14061; data type or length of an index partitioning column may not be changed.

*Cause: User issued ALTER TABLE statement attempting to modify data type and/or length of a column used to partition some index defined on the table named in ALTER TABLE statement, which is illegal
*Action: Avoid modifying data type and/or length of index partitioning column(s)
```

I understand why the error is thrown and the recommended action to avoid, however as usual it's out of my hands so i'm attempting the following work around found [here](https://developpaper.com/ora-14061-cannot-change-data-type-or-length-of-index-partition-column/):

```
ALTER TABLE ALTERNATIVETRADE#B DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B; --1

DROP INDEX PK_ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B; --2

ALTER TABLE ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B MODIFY (ALTERNATIVEID VARCHAR2(52)); --3

ALTER TABLE ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B PRIMARY KEY ("DEALID", "TRADEID", "ALTERNATIVEID", "ALTERNATIVEIDTYPE") USING INDEX TABLESPACE "TS_TRADE_DATA"; --4

ALTER TABLE ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B ENABLE CONSTRAINT PK_ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B; --5
```

My issue arises from statement --2, resulting in the following error:

```
DROP INDEX "PK_ALTERNATIVETRADEID#B"
ORA-01418: specified index does not exist
*Cause
*Action
```

The index is definitely named correctly in the SQL statement, however i'm assuming that it no longer exists because it was removed when the constraint was removed. Is that correct?

If so, how can I then achieve my original goal as executing statement --3 after dropping the constraint still results in the ORA-14061 error.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 17.

Thanks in advance and apologies for essentially asking two questions.

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about the PK index - you don't have another index on the table that references that column?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes - there is only one other constraint on the table that is a foreign key constraint. PK index is the only one that is named.

Comment: "PK index is the only one that is named" - not sure what you mean; all indexes have names, even if those are system-generated. It's also common to have an index matching the FK, but you haven't said whether than involves the column you're altering. The full DDL for the table, including all constraints and indexes, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to see your entire DDL because the approach you're taking is correct, so you must be missing some element.

eg

```
SQL> create table t
  2  as select owner, object_name, to_char(object_id) object_id
  3  from dba_objects
  4  where object_id is not null;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create unique index t_pk on t ( object_id )
  2  global partition by hash ( object_id ) partitions 8;

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key ( object_id )
  2  using index;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t modify object_id varchar2(64);
alter table t modify object_id varchar2(64)
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14061: data type or length of an index partitioning column may not be changed


SQL>
SQL> alter table t drop constraint t_pk;

Table altered.

SQL> drop index t_pk;

Index dropped.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t modify object_id varchar2(64);

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> create unique index t_pk on t ( object_id )
  2  global partition by hash ( object_id ) partitions 8;

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key ( object_id )
  2  using index;

Table altered.
```